# Render Template won't work for some reason

Tags: python, docker, flask

Please help I'm following a tutorial for flask but every time I try to build up this one application the route returns an internal server error and the problem seems to be with "render template".

Here's how I structured my app:

"python" 
|_books.py
|_DockerFile

| 
|_templates 
    index.html

Here's the code in each of the files.

-> **books.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@app.route('/')
def Hello():
    return '''<h1> Reading Archive</h1>
<p>A what would u like to read today?.</p>'''

@app.route('/books') #route 2
def books():
    return render_template("index.html")
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0','3333')
```

->**DockerFile**

```
FROM python:3
ADD books.py /
RUN pip install flask
RUN pip install requests
RUN pip install flask_restful
EXPOSE 3333
CMD [ "python", "./books.py"]
```

-> **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>
        A Small Library!
    </title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>** Library ** </h1>
    <h3><u> Books in the Library:</u></h3>

    <p><b>Title: </b><i>Astrophysics For People in a Hurry</i> <br>
        <b>Author: </b> Neil DeGrasse Tyson <br>
        <b>About:</b> Basic questions about the universe put into simple words by everyone's favourite scientist. <br>
        <b>Year published: </b> 2017 <br>
        <b>Genre: </b> Science, Non-Fiction. <br>
        </p>

        <p><b>Title: </b><i>The Shadow over Innsmouth</i><br>

            <b>Author: </b> H.P Lovecraft<br>
            <b>About:</b> A small fishing town in Massachusetts hides a dark secret underneath its shores.<br>
            <b>Year published: </b> 1936<br>
            <b>Genre: </b> Lovecraftian Horror.<br>
            </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The HTML file works perfectly fine on its own and the first Route from books.py works fine except with I type /books in Docker.
Please note I'm super new to Flask and I'm still learning. Thanks if you've answered!

Comment: Your DockerFile only copies `books.py`, it does not copy any of your other files. Unless you copy or mount them they will not be accessible to processes in your container

Comment: Adding on to @IainShelvington's point. Instead of `ADD books.py /`, change it to `COPY . /`

Comment: What is the difference between COPY and ADD?

Comment: @NavNaz for your use-case there is no difference. I would also suggest moving the copy/add to after the pip installs, your code will change often and your requirements will not. As you have it each build will trigger an install every time your code changes

Comment: Just did all the changes, however it keeps returning this error: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html